# How to connect redux to a none default component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, high-order-component

I have a file with multi component that I want to export and connect all to redux, how can I do this?

Connect wrapper need to export default, but I have multi component.

Comment: You are not forced to export default something in Redux. it's a choice. You can do named export and everything should works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to export default to use connect. You can connect multiple components within the same file, with or without exporting them. Although I would recommend only placing 1 component per file

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// This also works without the export statement
export const Comp1 = connect(
    state => ({
        someProp: state,
    })
)(({ someProp }) => (
    <div>
        <h1>Comp 1</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
))

const Comp2 = connect(
    state => ({
        someProp: state,
    })
)(({ someProp }) => (
    <div>
        <h1>Comp 2</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
))

export default Comp2
```

Answer (score -1):

`redux` doesn't provide any default export. always you connect to redux using `react-redux` whenever you need.
If you want some of the `dispatch` or `state` pass on your child component through parent component then connect `redux` on your parent component and then `destructure` the `props` at child component. then all `dispatch` and `state` available on parent and child component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Component1 from './component1'
import Component2 from './component2'
import { sampleDispathFunction } from './actions'

const WrapperComponent = (props) => {

  return <div>
    <Component1 {...props} />
    <Component2 {...props} />
  </div>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
  customer: state.customer
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  sampleDispathFunction: (data) => dispatch(sampleDispathFunction(data))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WrapperComponent);
```